# Buttons are un-clickable when resized to below tablet size

Tags: html, css

I want it can be clicked in ALL media queries. Please help to fix.
Even in w3schools, the buttons can't be clicked when below tablet size.

Here is the website of w3schools sample : http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_scrollspy2&stacked=h

Here is the css code.

```
body {
      position: relative;
  }
  ul.nav-pills {
      top: 300px;
      position: fixed;
  }
  div.col-sm-9 div {
      height: 250px;
      font-size: 28px;
  }

  #account_register {color: #fff; background-color: #1E88E5;}
  #login_logout {color: #fff; background-color: #673ab7;}
  #buying_process {color: #fff; background-color: #ff9800;}


  @media screen and (max-width: 810px) {
    #account_register, #login_logout, #buying_process, #business_register, #upload_product, #sort_product,  #sort_orders, #permission_management, #communicate {
        margin-left: 150px;
    }
```

Here is the html code.

```
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!--<div class="col-sm-6"><img src="images/test.png"></div><div class="col-sm-6"><span class="pull-center"><img src="images/test.png"></span></div>-->
        <div class="col-sm-12">

<nav class="col-sm-3" id="myScrollspy">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li><a href="#account_register">account_register</a></li>
    <li><a href="#login_logout">login_logout</a></li>
    <li><a href="#buying_process">buying_process</a></li>

  </ul>         
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="col-sm-9">
  <div id="account_register">    
    <h1>buying_process</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
  </div>

  <div id="login_logout">  <hr>
    <h1>login_logout</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
  </div>

  <div id="buying_process">  <hr>   
    <h1>buying_process</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
  </div>




</div>
```

Comment: There is nothing but just remove position style

Comment: Please check my answer bellow for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems z-index problem. Please check this [**link**](http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FBEI5KYPRO69)

```
 ul.nav-pills {
      top: 20px;
      position: fixed;
      z-index:1;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the position from style

```
body {
      position: relative;
  }
```

Just copy and past this code..

```
ul.nav-pills {
      top: 300px;
      position: fixed;
  }
  div.col-sm-9 div {
      height: 250px;
      font-size: 28px;
  }

  #account_register {color: #fff; background-color: #1E88E5;}
  #login_logout {color: #fff; background-color: #673ab7;}
  #buying_process {color: #fff; background-color: #ff9800;}


  @media screen and (max-width: 810px) {
    #account_register, #login_logout, #buying_process, #business_register, #upload_product, #sort_product,  #sort_orders, #permission_management, #communicate {
        margin-left: 150px;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!--<div class="col-sm-6"><img src="images/test.png"></div><div class="col-sm-6"><span class="pull-center"><img src="images/test.png"></span></div>-->
        <div class="col-sm-12">

<nav class="col-sm-3" id="myScrollspy">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li><a href="#account_register">account_register</a></li>
    <li><a href="#login_logout">login_logout</a></li>
    <li><a href="#buying_process">buying_process</a></li>

  </ul>         
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="col-sm-9">
  <div id="account_register">    
    <h1>buying_process</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
  </div>

  <div id="login_logout">  <hr>
    <h1>login_logout</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
  </div>

  <div id="buying_process">  <hr>   
    <h1>buying_process</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
  </div>




</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the user need to know what the issue is. By copy paste the code didn;t tell him what the issue is

Comment: I have mention above there is the issue for position

Comment: we didn't find any data related to it. we are seeing just copy paste this code.

Comment: Kindly Remove this style   body {
      position: relative;
  }

Comment: @CharantejGolla I have mention above, Please check for the same

Comment: @CharantejGolla I kindly request to you please check

Comment: What was the problem and how did you fix it?

Comment: @nicael I just remove the position from style

Comment: @nicael I just remove the  body { position: relative; }  from style

Comment: Please mention the same in your answer. Mentioning issues under the question wont help the others to find the issue. No one is ready to read comments under the question and go to solution. Always prefer to go for the solution with minimum data

Comment: @CharantejGolla Please check I have update my answer

Comment: @CharantejGolla Thank you so much

Comment: i just want to let you know how users prefer answer's. sorry if i'm rude.